# Magento group products

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a package of products i.e. a package can have products A,B,C.

Now, I've gone through the steps of creating grouped products but I want to allow customer to choose color & size as well.

I did some google but not getting anywhere. So, if someone have some link or tutorial, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento does not allow configurable products inside the grouped products.
But you can do this.
Let's say you have a configurable product by size (M,L) and color (Red, Blue).
So you must have 4 simple products, one for each combination of size and color.
You can add these simple products in the grouped product so the customer will see this:

```
Product X - red M 
Product X - red L 
Product X - blue M 
Product X - blue L
```

And he can choose what products to add to the cart.